# Vuejs Not Sending auth token to the server

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs2, http-headers, access-token

I cannot access API protected routes because VueJS is not sending auth token to nodejs server. This was initially working just fine, but it just stopped working. Login and storage of the token in front end is working as expected. Access the same routes via postman with token works just fine.
This is main.js

```
Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token']=localStorage.getItem('token')
Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';
```

**Doing this: console.log(Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common)** prints an object with x-access-token. This a clear indication that the token is being stored in the local storage and passed successfully to main.js.
The problem is that the token is not being send to the server with http requests**.
My Auth.js Middleware**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];

module.exports = (req, res, next)=>{

    const token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if(!token){
        return res.status(400).json({message:'No token provided!'})
    }

try{
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token,config.secret);
req.userData = decoded;
console.log(decoded)
return next();
}
catch(error){
return res.status(401).json({message:'Auth Failed!'});
}
};
```

**Server Response:**

```
`No Token Provided`!
```

I have included the following in app.js to resolve CORS issue and I don't think this is due to CORS.

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS
```

Any help, may I am doing something wrong in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If a server is expecting the bearer token then you can pass that in the `Authorization Header`, see the code sample below which retrieves the token from your local storage and sets that to the default header.

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to assist. I had tried all this. The issue is the token headers is not hitting the server. The paradox is it used to work just fine. But just stopped working.

Comment: Can you please use a Postman or any other tool to ensure that you are able to authenticate yourself and get the token out of the server?

Comment: I had already tested it with postman. It works just fine. Its only vuejs that is not sending the token.

Comment: Can you please post the entire code for us to take a look including the import...

Comment: Sure. But as to my understanding I had shared key information that are affecting the outcome. The snippet shared is everything that touches the problem. Do you mean the server.js, controllers or specifically what?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I am able to print the user token in the console from main.js

Comment: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", x-access-token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6I…UxMX0.f0Q21F7YAhcRIdQnCgBFc0EJoPJZfz1eSuMQERQfOTs"}

Comment: I am also able to access protected routes with the same token using postman. It turns out that the token or rather headers are not being send and thats exactly the issue. For unknown reasons, it just stopped working and thats is it.